# How to show Associate products status on Product Detail Page?

Tags: magento

I want to show Associate products Stock status on configurable detail page. Like when option selected in drop down then product status will be change.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please install the extension listed here @ 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5RZxA4F3j3KSVc0Sm9tZGR1dGM and replace the file of your theme from this location file "app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\type\options" of this extension.